# Rounding without CurrencyGroupSeparator

Tags: powershell, math, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to output a value from Powershell to Nagios. I want a clean number with only a . for decimals, not separator for 1000 and 1000000 and always 5 decimals even if it are trailing zeroes.

At first I had this:

```
$DiskStruct.AvgDiskReadQueueValue = '{0:N5}' -f ($AvgObjDiskReadQueueValues.average)
```

But this resulted in:
2205.06040082681
converted in:
2,205.06040

So then I tried

```
$DiskStruct.AvgDiskReadQueueValue = [decimal][math]::Round($AvgObjDiskReadQueueValues.average, 5)
```

But somehow this caused the Powershell script to sometimes output in scientific notation. And it did not show the trailing zeroes.
Result => Read/s = 2205.0604

So what can I do to always output 5 decimals, but not show any currencygroupseparator?

```
(Get-Culture).NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator
```

The result I would need is 2205.06040.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I posted this as a comment at first but I guess the possibility isn't immediately obvious so having an answer here may be useful.

`{0:Nx}` turns number into a string which can be cast back to any suitable numeric type. Since you want to preserve decimals:

```
[decimal]('{0:N5}' -f ($AvgObjDiskReadQueueValues.average))
```

is what you want.

---

To make this solution culture-independent you can use [a little trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/25/583235.aspx):

```
$OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = "en-US"

# Do culture-sensitive stuff here. 
# (As long as it doesn't execute in a different thread.)
[decimal]('{0:N5}' -f ($AvgObjDiskReadQueueValues.average))

[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
```

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work yet for me. Just fyi, the issue is in this nagios plugin (https://github.com/willemdh/check_ms_win_disk_load) Just in case somone would like to test.
When using your solution I get no decimals
OK: Drive C: Avg of 2 samples: {Rate (Read: 0MB/s)(Write: 6229MB/s)} {Avg Nr of (Reads: 0r/s)(Writes: 397959w/s)} {Latency (Read: 0ms)(Write: 116334ms)} {Queue Length (Read: 0ql)(Write: 499ql)} | 'Read_Latency'=0ms 
'Write_Latency'=116334ms 'Read_Queue'=0ql 'Write_Queue'=499ql 'Number_of_Reads'=0r/s 'Number_of_Writes'=397959w/s 'Read_Rate'=0MB/s 'Write_Rate'=6229MB/s

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? I'm not familiar with nagios but `[decimal]('{0:N5}' -f 2205.06040082681)` returns `2205.06040` - exactly what you wanted. If you need this value to be a string instead of decimal you can further cast it to `[string]`.

Comment: It's removing the decimals completely in the script. When using in shell I get
[decimal]('{0:N5}' -f 2205.06040082681)
Cannot convert value "2 205,06040" to type "System.Decimal". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: I found a workaround which does what I want though. Ill answer the question with it. Thanks for the help. You did point me in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, your thread culture isn't `en-US`. Well, there's a generic workaround for such situations. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this

`$Separator = (Get-Culture).NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator
$DiskStruct.AvgDiskSecReadValue = ('{0:N5}' -f ([math]::Round(($AvgObjDiskSecReadValues.average * 1000), 5))).replace("$Separator",'')`

By first asking the separator and then replacing it with nothing I get what I want. 
Changed it back to Alexander's solutions, as it seems cleaner.